# angularJS - ng-repeat: Error: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to display a list of items with I get from twitter API. My problem is that while my request is processing angular is trying to print the empty list and therefore I get this error message:

```
Error: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: ...
```

How can I prevent this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

add `track by $index` at the end of your ng-repeat="". That'll avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I read this to be some sort of race condition. Are you using a $promise to represent the data you are getting from Twitter?

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

You may also want to look into the $watch functionality which will allow you to watch an object for changes and take action only after the pull/transformation is complete.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope